# What is the proper way to test that a controller appropriately handles a uniqueness validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, controller

**Summary**

I am building a Rails app which includes a user registration process. A `username` and `password` are necessary to create a `user` object in the database; the `username` must be unique. **I am looking for the right way to test that the uniqueness validation prompts a particular action of a controller method**, namely `UsersController#create`.

**Context**

The user model includes the relevant validation:

```
# app/models/user.rb
#
#  username        :string           not null
#  ...

class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :username, presence: true
# ... more validations, class methods, and instance methods
end
```

Moreover, the spec file for the `User` model tests this validation using [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers):

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:username)}
# ... more model tests
end
```

The method `UsersController#create` is defined as follows:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      render :show
    else
      flash[:errors] = @user.errors.full_messages
      redirect_to new_user_url
    end
  end
# ... more controller methods
end
```

Since the `User` spec for `username` uniqueness passes, I *know* that a `POST` request which contains a `username` already in the database will cause `UsersController#create` to enter the `else` portion of the conditional, and I want a test to verify this situation.

Currently, I test how `UsersController#create` handles the uniqueness validation on `username` in the following manner:

```
# spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  describe 'POST #create' do
    context "username exists in db" do
      before(:all) do
        User.create!(username: 'jarmo', password: 'good_password')
      end

      before(:each) do
        post :create, params: { user: { username: 'jarmo', password: 'better_password' }}
      end

      after(:all) do
        User.last.destroy
      end

      it "redirects to new_user_url" do
        expect(response).to redirect_to new_user_url
      end

      it "sets flash errors" do
        should set_flash[:errors]
      end
    end
# ... more controller tests
end
```

**Issue**

My primary concern is the `before` and `after` hooks. Without `User.last.destroy`, this test will fail when run in the future: The new record can't be created, and thus the creation of a *second* record with the same `username` doesn't occur.

**Question**

Should I be testing this particular model validation in the controller spec? If so, are these hooks the right/best way to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll steer away from an opinion on the 'should I...' part, but there are a couple of aspects worth considering. First, although controller tests have not been formally deprecated, they have generally been discouraged by both the Rails and Rspec teams for a while now. From the RSpec 3.5 [release notes](http://rspec.info/blog/2016/07/rspec-3-5-has-been-released/):

> The official recommendation of the Rails team and the RSpec core team
> is to write request specs instead. Request specs allow you to focus on
> a single controller action, but unlike controller tests involve the
> router, the middleware stack, and both rack requests and responses.
> This adds realism to the test that you are writing, and helps avoid
> many of the issues that are common in controller specs.

Whether or not the scenario warrants a corresponding request spec is a judgement call, but if you want to unit test the validation at the model level, check out the [shoulda matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem, which assists with model validation testing).

In terms of your question about hooks, `before(:all)` hooks run outside a database transaction, so even if you have `use_transactional_fixtures` set to `true` in your RSpec configuration, they won't be automatically rolled back. So, a matching `after(:all)` like you have is the way to go. Alternatives include:

1. Creating the user inside a `before(:each)` hook, which does run in a transaction and is rolled back. That's at the potential cost of some test performance.
2. Use a tool like the [Database Cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) gem, which gives you fine-grained control over the strategies for cleaning your test databases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cover the controller together with the user feedback aspect of this I would suggest a feature spec:

```
RSpec.feature "User creation" do
  context "with duplicate emails" do
    let!(:user) { User.create!(username: 'jarmo', password: 'good_password') }

    it "does not allow duplicate emails" do
      visit new_user_path
      fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
      fill_in 'Password', with: 'p4ssw0rd'
      fill_in 'Password Confirmation', with: 'p4ssw0rd'
      expect do
        click_button 'Sign up'
      end.to_not change(User, :count)
      expect(page).to have_content 'Email has already been taken'
    end
  end
end
```

Instead of poking inside the controller this drives the full stack from the user story and tests that the view actually has an output for the validation errors as well - it thus provides value where a controller spec provides very little value.

Use `let/let!` to setup givens for a particular example as it has the advantage that you can reference them in the example through the helper method it generates. `before(:all)` should generally be avoided apart from stuff like stubbing out API's. Each example should have its own setup/teardown.

But you also need to deal with the fact that the controller itself is broken. It should read:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

When a record is invalid you should NOT redirect back. Render the form again as you're displaying the result of performing a POST request. Redirecting back will make for a horrible user experience since all the fields will be blanked out.

When creating a resource is successful you should redirect the user to the newly created resource so that the browser URL actually points to the new resource. If you don't reloading the page will load the index instead.

This also removes the need to stuff the error messages in the session. If you want to give useful feedback through the flash you would do it like so:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Signup failed."
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

And you can test it with:

```
expect(page).to have_content "Signup failed."
```